# Pandas: plot nested Series in DataFrame columns as per-column subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of Series nested inside of a DataFrame as cells.

```
pd.DataFrame(data={('SUPER-COLUMN', 'a'): [pd.Series([1,2,3]), pd.Series([10,20,30])], ('SUPER-COLUMN', 'b'): [pd.Series([101,102,103]), pd.Series([1001, 1002, 1003])]})
```

I would like to plot the DataFrame 'SUPER-COLUMN' columns as a figure of two (in this case) subplots, where each subplot should correspond to a column (eg, 'a', 'b'), and each subplot should have two lines (in this case), one for each row of the DataFrame.

**Important:** Note that I do not know in advance how many columns (and their names) are in SUPER-COLUMN.

Ideally, `df['SUPER-COLUMN'].plot(subplots=True)` would produce:

subplot title 'a': line1: [1, 2, 3], line2: [101, 102, 103]

subplot title 'b': line1: [10, 20, 30], line2: [1001, 1002, 1003]

Least amount of non pandas (eg, matplotlib) would be appreciated.

Comment: try to consider multiple index or even list of dataframe with for loop

Comment: Wouldn't a for loop on a list of dataframes produce multiple plots instead of subplots?